# Ansible become_user useradd issue

Tags: linux, ansible

When trying to add a user using Ansible, I set `ansible_become_user` in my inventory to an account on the server that is a `sudoer`, but adding a user still fails with this error:

```
usermod: cannot open /etc/passwd usermod: failed to unlock /etc/passwd
```

I tested on the server running the command like this from my normal ssh account:

```
sudo -u <sudo_user> useradd test
useradd: cannot open /etc/passwd
useradd: failed to unlock /etc/passwd
```

If I `su` to my `sudo` account and run `sudo useradd test`, it works just fine.

I can also get it to work from my base SSH account by running `su <sudo_user> -c "sudo useradd test"`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable to set on your playbook/task is `become_user` not `ansible_become_user`. `ansible_become_user` is used when you set the value for a specific host/group in your inventory. See the [privilege escalation doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)

Moreover, you also have to set `become: true` for the above option to have any effect.

A quick example (does not become anything with debug, just to put you on track)

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: someone

  tasks:
    - name: dummy task with play's defaults
      debug:
        msg: I would run with play's become_user

    - name: dummy task with overriden user
      become_user: some_other
      debug:
        msg: I would run with the overriden become_user
```

Comment: I set ansible_become_user and ansible_become in the inventory. If i set them both there, do I still have to set become for the specific task? It seems like it already tries to become from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another option, that is execute it like other user, for example root, and try it again.

For do it, edit `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

Then search for:

```
JENKINS_USER="jenkins"
```

And change it for

```
JENKINS_USER="root"
```

This should resolve the issue.

Another way is to add jenkins to visudo